# Is it possible to tell if all checkboxes are checked on a dynamic form?

Tags: php

I have a form which can populate from 1-100 elements based on a user's internal preferences. On my subsequent php page, i want to divert action if ALL checkboxes from the previous page are checked. I know checkboxes can come through as an array but I am unable to develop a solution for both a single array (one name, several boxes, e.g. types of fruit) or multiple arrays (several fields with different types, e.g. `fruit[], cars[], magazines[]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better add an hidden input with the total number of checkboxes than simply compare that number with the array size.

Comment: Note that this implicitly trusts the client, which is probably fine, but good to keep in mind.